# How do I install the info files for org-mode version 7.5 on Windows XP?

Tags: windows, emacs, windows-xp, org-mode

I am attempting to install org-mode 7.5 on a Windows XP machine but `M-x org-info` brings up the documentation for Org version 6.33x that shipped with Emacs 23.3.1

I downloaded the zip file and extracted it to "~/.emacs.d/org-7.5/":

```
c:/Documents and Settings/myusername/Application Data/.emacs.d/org-7.5:
total used in directory 16 available 279614668
drwxrwxrwx  1 myusername Domain Users     0 04-08 09:50 .
drwxrwxrwx  1 myusername Domain Users     0 04-08 09:58 ..
-rw-rw-rw-  1 myusername Domain Users 14168 03-07 13:29 Makefile
-rw-rw-rw-  1 myusername Domain Users  1051 03-07 13:29 README
drwxrwxrwx  1 myusername Domain Users     0 04-08 09:50 contrib
drwxrwxrwx  1 myusername Domain Users     0 04-08 09:50 doc
drwxrwxrwx  1 myusername Domain Users     0 04-08 10:10 lisp
-rw-rw-rw-  1 myusername Domain Users  1007 03-07 13:29 request-assign-future.txt
```

In [Section 1.2 "Installation"](http://orgmode.org/manual/Installation.html#Installation) of [*The Org Manual*](http://orgmode.org/manual/index.html#Top) the directions say to edit the shipped Makefile and then run `make`. Being a Windows machine, this will not work.

```
C:\Documents and Settings\myusername\Application Data\.emacs.d\org-7.5>make
make
'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

So what added the following line to my `~/.emacs.d/init.el` file:

```
(setq load-path (cons "~/.emacs.d/org-7.5/lisp" load-path))
```

Restarted emacs and then did a byte compile of the Org 7.5 lisp directory:

```
ELISP> (version)
"GNU Emacs 23.3.1 (i386-mingw-nt5.1.2600)\n of 2011-03-10 on 3249CTO"
ELISP> load-path

("~/.emacs.d/org-7.5/lisp" "~/.emacs.d" <snip>)

ELISP> (byte-recompile-directory "~/.emacs.d/org-7.5/lisp/" 0 t)
"Done (Total of 99 files compiled)"
```

Then added the following lines to init.el:

```
(require 'org-install)
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.org\\'" . org-mode))
(global-set-key "\C-col" 'org-store-link)
(global-set-key "\C-coc" 'org-capture)
(global-set-key "\C-coa" 'org-agenda)
(global-set-key "\C-cob" 'org-iswitchb)
(setq org-log-done t)
```

Restarted emacs again. Now Org 7.5 is installed:

```
ELISP> org-version
"7.5"
```

But the steps performed do not create or install info files such that when I use `M-x org-info` I get the manual for Org version 7.5 instead of 6.33x:

```
File: org,  Node: Top,  Next: Introduction,  Prev: (dir),  Up: (dir)

Org Mode Manual
***************

This manual is for Org version 6.33x.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a line to .emacs or .emacs.d/init.el as appropriate that includes
the documentation shipped with Org 7.5 in the
`Info-default-directory-list`:

```
; Find the Org documentation
(setq Info-default-directory-list 
  (cons "~/.emacs.d/org-7.5/doc/" Info-default-directory-list))
```

This does lead one weirdness, that when info mode is started (say with `M-x info` or `C-h i`) Org Mode is now the top line in the Menu, before the main Emacs help.

```
File: dir,  Node: Top   This is the top of the INFO tree

  <snip>

* Menu:

Emacs
* Org Mode: (org).      Outline-based notes management and organizer

* Info: (info).                 How to use the documentation browsing system.
* Emacs: (emacs).               The extensible self-documenting text editor.
* Emacs FAQ: (efaq).            Frequently Asked Questions about Emacs.
* <snip>
```

Also, I found `org-info` was not available until org-mode had been used at least once, I added the following line to make it always available:

```
(require 'org-info)
```

**NOTE:** The [emacs wiki entry on InfoPath](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/InfoPath) recommends using the `INFOPATH` environment variable instead of `Info-default-directory-list` on non Windows machines.